# How to target the contents inside a text blob?

Tags: javascript, html, blob, textarea

I'll keep it short. The following is the method I'm using in order to convert the text inside a textarea tag to a .txt file:

```html
<textarea id="inputTextToSave"></textarea>

 

<button onclick="saveTextAsFile()">SAVE</button>

<textarea id="string"></textarea>

<script>

function saveTextAsFile()

{
    var textToWrite = document.getElementById("inputTextToSave").value;
    var textFileAsBlob = new Blob([textToWrite], {type:'text/plain;charset=utf-8'});
    


document.getElementById("string").innerHTML= textFileAsBlob.txt;
}

    </script>
```

The issue is whenever I run the function and try to insert the blob content from 'inputTextToSave' textarea in the 'string' textarea, it doesn't render the text. Essentially I'm trying to target the contents inside the blob so that I can later upload them to a database and that db only accepts .txt files. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `await textFileAsBlob.text()` to convert blob to string (don't forget to declare your function as `async` to use `await` method, because `Blob.text()` method returns `Promise`, not the actual result).

Example:

```
import { Blob } from 'buffer';

const textFileAsBlob = new Blob(['xxxx'], {type:'text/plain;charset=utf-8'});
console.log(`textFileAsBlob = ${textFileAsBlob}`)

const stringFromBlob = await textFileAsBlob.text()
console.log(`stringFromBlob = ${stringFromBlob}`)
```

Result:
[image]

Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/text

Code Snippet based on your code:

```js
async function saveTextAsFile() {
    const textToWrite = document.getElementById("inputTextToSave").value;
    const textFileAsBlob = new Blob([textToWrite], {type:'text/plain;charset=utf-8'});
    document.getElementById("string").innerHTML= await textFileAsBlob.text();
}
```

```html
<textarea id="inputTextToSave"></textarea>
<button onclick="saveTextAsFile()">SAVE</button>
<textarea id="string"></textarea>
```

Comment: So I did try to use .text() and set the .innerHTML of the textarea to textFileAsBlob.text() but I still don't get the text inside. Anything I'm missing? @StayPerfect

Comment: @Singh updated my answer with code snippet based on your code. It should work now as you asked. 

I think your problem was that you didn't init your function as 'async' to use 'await' keyword. The main reason why we need to do that, is because 'Blob.text()' returns not the text result, but Promise that we need to 'await' to get the final result.